# Script Inserção no Banco PHP

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando inserir dados vindos de um formulário no banco, mas não está salvando no BD. Não consegui detectar o erro. Qualquer ajuda será válida.

```
<?php
require('login/autenticacao_usuario.php');
require('login/verificar_acesso.php');
require('BDconexao/conexao.php');
require('Agencia/funcoesAgencia.php'); //Função cadastrarAgencia encontra-se nesse arquivo
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <link href="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
            <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
              <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><!--<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>--><img src="images/simbolo-logo.png"><span></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- menu profile quick info -->
            <div class="profile clearfix">
              <div class="profile_pic">
                <img src="images/user.png" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
              </div>
              <div class="profile_info">

                <span>Bem-vindo(a),</span>
                <h2><?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['usuario']);?></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /menu profile quick info -->
            <br />

            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
              <div class="menu_section">
                <h3>Menu Geral</h3>
                <ul class="nav side-menu">
                  <li><a href="Home-Admin.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron"></span></a>
                   </li>
                  <li><a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Agências <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                      <li><a href="cadastrar_agencia.html">Cadastrar Agência</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Lista de Agências</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>                  
                   <li><a><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Gerentes <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Gerente</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Lista de Gerentes</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>  
                  <li><a><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> MIP por Agência <span class="fa fa-chevron"></span></a>

                  </li>  
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="menu_section">
                <h3>Minha Agência</h3>
                <ul class="nav side-menu">
                  <li><a><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Funcionários <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Funcionário</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Lista de Funcionários</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                   <li><a><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Quadro de Eletricistas<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Quadro</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Visualizar Quadro</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li> 
                   <li><a><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Turnos<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Turno</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Visualizar Turnos</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li><a><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> MIP <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">

                        <li><a>Ocorrências Previstas<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                          <ul class="nav child_menu">
                            <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Cadastrar Ocorrências</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Visualizar Ocorrências</a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a>Ocorrências Realizadas<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                          <ul class="nav child_menu">
                            <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Cadastrar Ocorrências</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Visualizar Ocorrências</a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li> 


                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- top navigation -->

        <div class="top_nav">
        <center><span style="color:white;">Agência: <?php echo ($_SESSION['agencia']);?></span></center>             
          <div class="nav_menu">

            <nav>
              <div class="nav toggle">
                <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                </div>

                             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="">
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="images/user.png" alt=""><?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['usuario']);?>
                    <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;">Perfil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i>Sair</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                            </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /top navigation -->

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
          <!-- top tiles -->

          <!-- /top tiles -->

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            </div>

          </div>
          <br />

          <div class="row">


             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Cadastrar nova agência</h2>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    <form action="<?php cadastrarAgencia(); ?>" method="POST"  class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Descrição Agência:*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input name="descricao" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Consórcio Salvador" required="">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Estado:*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <select class="select2_single form-control" name="estado" tabindex="-1" required="">

                              <option value="">Selecione o Estado</option> 
                              <option value="ac">Acre</option> 
                              <option value="al">Alagoas</option> 
                              <option value="am">Amazonas</option> 
                              <option value="ap">Amapá</option> 
                              <option value="ba">Bahia</option> 
                              <option value="ce">Ceará</option> 
                              <option value="df">Distrito Federal</option> 
                              <option value="es">Espírito Santo</option> 
                              <option value="go">Goiás</option> 
                              <option value="ma">Maranhão</option> 
                              <option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option> 
                              <option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option> 
                              <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option> 
                              <option value="pa">Pará</option> 
                              <option value="pb">Paraíba</option> 
                              <option value="pr">Paraná</option> 
                              <option value="pe">Pernambuco</option> 
                              <option value="pi">Piauí</option> 
                              <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option> 
                              <option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option> 
                              <option value="ro">Rondônia</option> 
                              <option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option> 
                              <option value="rr">Roraima</option> 
                              <option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option> 
                              <option value="se">Sergipe</option> 
                              <option value="sp">São Paulo</option> 
                              <option value="to">Tocantins</option> 
                            </select>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Cidade:*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" name="cidade" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Salvador" required="" >
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Limpar</button>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


                <!-- start of weather widget -->

                <!-- end of weather widget -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

        <!-- footer content -->
        <footer>
          <div class="pull-right">
            Copyright &copy; 2017 <a target="_blank" href="#"></a> - Todos os direitos reservados
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </footer>
        <!-- /footer content -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- Chart.js -->
    <script src="../vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- gauge.js -->
    <script src="../vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <script src="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="../vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Skycons -->
    <script src="../vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot -->
    <script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot plugins -->
    <script src="../vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
    <!-- DateJS -->
    <script src="../vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <script src="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <script src="../vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="../build/js/custom.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo Funções Agencia:

```
<?php

   function cadastrarAgencia(){


  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
   $estado = $_POST['estado'];
   $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];


  try{

 $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
 $insere = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO agencia VALUES(null,:descricao_agencia,:estado_agencia,:cidade_agencia)");

    $insere->bindParam(':descricao_agencia',$descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insere->bindParam(':estado_agencia',$estado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insere->bindParam(':cidade_agencia',$cidade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insere->execute();

        if($insere!=NULL){

            print "<script> alert ('Agência cadastrada com sucesso!'); window.location.href='../cadastra_agencia.php'; </script>";


        }else{


            print "<script> alert ('Agência não cadastrada!'); window.location.href='../cadastra_agencia.php'; </script>";

        }

}catch(PDOException $e){

       echo $e->getMessage();

                       }

                        }
      }

     ?>
```

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum erro ?

Comment: Não, só dá reload na página. Fiz alguns testes,me parece que os dados do form estão vindo como nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode colocar na action do form a chamada da função php. Ele não reconhece. O correto é submeter o seu formúlario para a própria página do html e verificar se foi enviado post. Se sim dai chama a função cadastrarAgencia().

Altere o form action:

```
<form action="nome_arquivo_html_formulario" method="POST"  class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
```

No início do arquivo após os requires faça um teste se está sendo enviado um post.

```
<?php
require('login/autenticacao_usuario.php');
require('login/verificar_acesso.php');
require('BDconexao/conexao.php');
require('Agencia/funcoesAgencia.php'); //Função cadastrarAgencia encontra-se nesse arquivo
if(isset($_POST)){
  $this->cadastrarAgencia();
?>
```